# cvLoadImage dont show new image and load previous image

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt, opencv3.0

I'm trying to load new image with {IplImage} function. it works fine until I closed the project totally and again import it. now when I want to load new image with this function it doesn't work. I tried rebuild and change the debug to release but none one them did not worked.

```
IplImage* img =  cvLoadImage("images.jpg");
//show the original image
cvNamedWindow("Raw");
cvShowImage("Raw",img);
```

Comment: Don't use obsolete C api!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems it was eclipse cdt problem i reinstall it and everything works good now.
Thank you all.